# Conditional Probability - When is $P(A|B)=P(A)$?

Tags: probability

Is it because $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ do not multipy anywhere on the probability tree (tree made of only 1 stage/branch). $P(A|B)=\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=P(A)$ ?

Comment: $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are just numbers, so it doesn't really make sense to wonder whether they intersect. On the other hand, if $A$ does not intersect $B$, then $P(A\cap B) = 0$ regardless. This means that $P(A\mid B) = 0$, and this makes it unlikely that $P(A) = P(A\mid B)$.

Comment: Hmmm... $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ if and only if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Not much more to say, I am afraid...

Answer (score 4):

$P(A\mid B) = P(A)$ if and only if $P(A\cap B)/P(B) = P(A)$, which happens if and only if $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$. When we have this last condition we say that $A$ and $B$ are *independent*. Hence

> $P(A\mid B) = P(A)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

I really like this interpretation: $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if the probability of the event $A$ is not altered by the event $B$. For me, this has more intuition than the condition $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

By the way, as a consequence, the same holds if you switch the roles of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense